# ElasticSearch alternate searching words

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am matching a string from my elasticsearch index. Below are details

URL:

```
http://localhost:9200/postgresql.public.parcels/_search?scroll=10m&size=905&pretty
```

Body:

```
{

    "_source": ["city", "displayaddress", "society_name" ],

  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [
        { "match": { "displayaddress":   "Residential Plot No. 10"        }}
      ],
      "filter": [ 
        { "match":  { "second_param": "New York" }}
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
      {
      "plotno": {"order": "desc"}
    }
    ]

}
```

This query is retruning me perfect **displayaddress**, that have "Residential Plot No. 10".

What i want is that if user type **displayaddress** field like "House No. 10" or "Building No. 10" then it should consider it as "Residential Plot No. 10"

How can i do this with elasticsearch. Can i accomplish it with built-in queries or do i have to build some wrapper on it?

Comment: Consider using `minimum_should_match` to allow missing some query words?

Comment: basically it's more like a synomym  search i.e. if user type house no, then it should search from residential plot no.

Comment: Get it. Have you tried using a custom analyzer with `synonym token filter`?